# GitHub, Error while push to remote. I can't push large files

Tags: github, git-lfs

I cant push files into remote repository the error shown;

```
remote: error: Trace: 4826343039aab4a26cc11c6aa133f1e87a7f9dd314245a5c46cd6b500a048315
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File xxxxxx.csv is 143.84 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx-xxxxxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx-xxxxxx.git'
```

and i tried to solve this by installing LFS and after initialized I followed these steps

```
git add .gitattributes` and 
git add xxxxxx.csv
git commit -m "Add design file"
git push origin main
```

but i got the same error...please help me with this

Comment: You didn't add the file to tracking, and second why are you adding "file.psd" instead of "xxx.csv".
Here watch [tutorial](https://youtu.be/uLR1RNqJ1Mw?t=42) by github

Comment: Yes - it seems you did not use Git LFS correctly. Try to follow the steps outlined in https://git-lfs.github.com/ ("Getting started"). If it still does not work, edit your question with the exact problem you are facing. Voting to close as unclear in the meantime...

Comment: sorry i just copied from the git hub.....i used `git add xxxxxx.csv` instead of file.psd

Comment: @sleske thank you !!! You are right ,sleske